# How to hide last sharing icon?

Tags: android

In my app I added Easy Share Action, icon for sharing appeared in Action Bar. After sharing app , for example on facebook, facebook icon also displayed in Action Bar near sharing icon. Can I block this icons to apear in Action Bar, I dont need to be showed last share icon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the ShareActionProvider when creating your ActionBar, instead, just use a standard MenuItem (and set the icon to share).  Then you will not see the last share option.

Comment: I have this in my menu file

`<item
 android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="@string/defaulttext"
    app:showAsAction="always" 
 app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>`

Comment: Remove the: app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" attribute from your XML (to accomplish what I suggest).  Also, provide an img attribute (show your own share icon that you will need to include in your project).

Answer (score 0):

As @Booger said.

For example with text:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_share -> { 
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type = "text/plain"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your_text")
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        }
        else -> {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```